# how to place objects in procedural generated world unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

So I have a procedurally generated world in unity which was made following some of sebastian lague's tutorials now I want to add trees but I just can't seem to figure out how.

here is what I have tried

`MapGenerator.cs`

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
  ...
    private Color[] GenerateColorMap(float[,] heightMap)
    {
        Color[] colorMap = new Color[mapWidth * mapHeight];

        // Looping through every pixel
        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
                if (useFalloff) {
                    heightMap[x,y] = Mathf.Clamp01(heightMap[x,y] - falloffMap[x,y]);
                }
                
                float currentHeight = heightMap[x, y];
                // Setting the color at that height to the regions color
                for (int i = 0; i < regions.Length; i++) {
                    if (currentHeight <= regions[i].height) {
                        colorMap[y * mapWidth + x] = regions[i].color;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return colorMap;
    }
    
    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        float[,] noiseMap = Noise.GenerateNoiseMap(mapWidth, mapHeight, octaves, seed, noiseScale, persistence, lacunarity, offset);
        Color[] colorMap = GenerateColorMap(noiseMap);

        ...

        else if (drawMode == DrawMode.mesh) {
            mapDisplay.DrawMesh(MeshGenerator.GenerateTerrainMesh(noiseMap, meshHeight, meshCurve, meshCollider), TextureGenerator.TextureFromColorMap(colorMap, mapWidth, mapHeight));

            PlaceTrees(noiseMap); // Does not work
        }
    }

    private void PlaceTrees(float[,] heightMap)
    {
        int width = heightMap.GetLength(0);
        int height = heightMap.GetLength(1);
        
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                if (Random.Range(0, 10) > x) {
                    GameObject tree = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab);
                    tree.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(x * 1, x * 100), heightMap[x,y], Random.Range(y * 1, y * 100));
                    tree.transform.parent = prefabPlaceholder.transform;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ClearObjects()
    {
        while (prefabPlaceholder.transform.childCount != 0) {
            DestroyImmediate(prefabPlaceholder.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        }
    }
   
   ...
}

[System.Serializable]
public struct Regions
{
    public string name;
    public float height;
    public Color color;
}
```

result of code

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this? I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while. If you need more files / screenshots please comment. Thanks again

Comment: well sounds like you multiplying the `x * 100` is simply way too far apart from where they should be?

Comment: Thanks but I also want to ask how will I check to make sure the tree is only on grass and not on water?

Comment: well first of all make sure it is not super far away from where it is supposed to be ;) .. and then you only check `if (Random.Range(0, 10) > x)` not sure why actually ... but here you want to add a check for which map type is at the given position

Comment: Ok lemme check it out

Comment: @derHugo Im afraid it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're randomly placing trees with an X value from 0 to 1, and a y value of 0 to 100. As another user stated in the comments, I think that range is just far bigger than the map you're actually generating. Ideally the range for tree placement should match your map dimensions, using `mapWidth` and `mapHeight`.

For correct placement of the trees on land, you should pass your `Color[] colorMap` array into the `PlaceTrees` method. For each pixel check the height to make sure that the pixel is "green land".

Note that `Random.Range(0, 10) > x` is not really a great way to randomly place a tree in this situation, given your dimensions. I don't know what your actual map dimensions are, but you may want something with a little more logic for this decision. You could probably create a method that checks the actual height for placement. Just because it's green, doesn't mean you want trees there. Maybe above a certain height, the terrain becomes mountains with fewer trees. At a certain elevation trees don't even really grow anymore. Same thing with the lower heights... maybe heights very close to sea level don't have trees (beaches).

For tree placement logic you could also check the surrounding pixels to see what type of water it's near... trees often grow along the edge of a river, but maybe not along the edge of a larger body of water like an ocean.

Comment: Hi thanks! But now when I try to implement this and try to test it it hangs Unity and if I don't forcefully close it, it hangs my laptop as well. There might be something wrong with how I did this so let me say what I did to make sure everything was correctly. I have 3 for loops 2 for the dimensions and another for color map; I then check if the color is green (for now I'm doing it like this) if it is spawn the tree using the code in the original question

Comment: @SajawalHassan it sounds like you have an infinite loop. Check your conditions for the loop ending, and that you're properly incrementing/decrementing/changing the corresponding value.